# Bootstrap 2.3.2 interfering to Google maps controls v.3

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I am new in bootstrap twitter my version is 2.3.2 and after including google maps into my site, google maps controls went to invisible, i made a search for this issue and everything I found it didnt work for me:
this code fixed the layout of controls but they still are untouchable

```
#map-canvas img { max-width: none ; max-height:none; }
#map-canvas label { width: auto; display: inline; }
```

also the dropdown menu right is deformed

```
<div class="span9">
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties):

> If you're using Google Maps on a Bootstrapped project, you might run into some display problems due to our use of * { box-sizing: border-box; }. Previously, you may have also ran into issues with the use of max-width on images. The following snippet should avoid all those problems.

```
 /* Fix Google Maps canvas
 *
 * Wrap your Google Maps embed in a `.google-map-canvas` to reset Bootstrap's
 * global `box-sizing` changes. You may optionally need to reset the `max-width`
 * on images in case you've applied that anywhere else. (That shouldn't be as
 * necessary with Bootstrap 3 though as that behavior is relegated to the
 * `.img-responsive` class.)
 */

.google-map-canvas,
.google-map-canvas * { .box-sizing(content-box); }

/* Optional responsive image override */
img { max-width: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
My bootstrap version is 2.3.2!? It doesn't work agian :(