# How to add zoom bar to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, prototypejs

I´m uasing prototype to add a feature with google maps but i'm unable to add zoom bar , in the following picture you could see that the zoom bar its missing

[image]

I tried by adding in initialize : function

```
         var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: true
              }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

but i didn't have succes (i think that this code it´s to be used only with javascript), i dont know if this zoom control should be added in other place, any idea where could be the solution ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue. `Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined`

Comment: do you use prototypejs in your application?

Comment: yes , i use prototype

Comment: do you also happen to use the bootstrap CSS or something similar? there is a image CSS in those files that completely collapses the zoom controls see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048329/bootstrap-2-3-2-interfering-to-google-maps-controls-v-3

Comment: no , its pure prototype js without css

Comment: I dont suppose this is hosted publicly so I could troubleshoot it directly, you can ping me @geeknum88 on twitter

Comment: Related: [Display zoom slider in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41095970/145173)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the controls in your code in order to get the zoom bar in your Map. The zoom control you are looking for can be obtained by adding the following line in your options variable.

```
zoomControl:true
```

You can add other controls too in your map.

```
panControl:true,
zoomControl:true,
mapTypeControl:true,
scaleControl:true,
streetViewControl:true,
overviewMapControl:true,
rotateControl:true
```

And instantiate them as following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.5456441,-1.159857),
zoom:7,
panControl:true,
zoomControl:true,
mapTypeControl:true,
scaleControl:true,
streetViewControl:true,
overviewMapControl:true,
rotateControl:true,    
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:450px;height:250px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this would Help !!!