# Display zoom slider in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there a way to show zoom control slider in google maps using their API (like in this image I have taken today from maps.google.com)?

**zoom slider control**

[image]

I tried setting **style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE** in the init, but it doesnt work.

You can look at this simple example - there are only zoom buttons, but no slider

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNORgv

```
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions: {                                           
                            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
                }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old zoom control has been removed. If you want to include one you'll need to custom make it. I only skimmed over [this](https://jrtashjian.com/2009/11/google-maps-api-custom-zoom-slider/) blog post about how to make one but it seems pretty comprehensive.

Essentially you'll need to create a custom HTML element and tie functions to detect changes in the slider and emit those to the Google Map

Comment: If it has been removed, why is it on maps.google.com?

Comment: That's probably a design decision so that legacy users don't get angry with it being gone. But it's existence doesn't mean that it is enabled through the API. They are capable of creating custom sliders as well. If you don't believe me then read through other stack overflow posts. They all say the same. And the Google Maps API Documentation doesn't have a spot anymore to enable the slider...

Comment: Reading through several articles, it seems like they removed it and than they brought it back? http://lifehacker.com/bring-back-the-zoom-slider-in-google-maps-1744634311

Comment: The article says "in Google maps". I think they mean specifically when using maps.google.com you can do this, but I don't think that would also extend to uses of the API. Honestly, I think you're chasing down a rabbit hole. If it were doable through the API Google would let us know. They have great documentation. I think you should cut this dream loose and start your custom slider

Comment: I guess you might be right. All I was thinking was that if google has the slider on their website, the functionality is somewhere in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard about the talkings about new version of maps will have vertical zoom slider that they will re-implement the slider for next version. we will wait and see what will they do for that. If you had any information about this please inform us too.